# How would I make a button to change the date? For a calendar

Tags: c#, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I got a calendar in my view, and I need a button to change the month, what I trying to do  is basically when you change the date of the OS it changes the calendar as well, I got that working I just need a button and I don't know how to do that or where to start.

@*This is my view, I dont feel like its necessary to show the model and the controller*@

```
    int currentMonth = DateTime.UtcNow.Month;
    int currentYear = DateTime.UtcNow.Year;
    DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, 1);
    DateTime lastDay = new DateTime(currentYear, currentMonth, Model.DaysOfMonth.Count);
    int dayOfWeekFirst = ((int)firstDay.DayOfWeek > 0) ? (int)firstDay.DayOfWeek : 7;


<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <table class="table color-table info-table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <th>SEG</th>
        <th>TER</th>
        <th>QUA</th>
        <th>QUI</th>
        <th>SEX</th>
        <th>SÁB</th>
        <th>DOM</th>
        </thead>
        <tr>
        <tbody>
            <!-- filling up space of previous month -->
            @for (int a = 1; a < dayOfWeekFirst; a++)
        {
        <td></td>
            }
            <!-- filling up space of current month -->
            @for (int i = Model.DaysOfMonth[0].DayOfMonth; i <= Model.DaysOfMonth.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime renderedDay = new DateTime(firstDay.Year, firstDay.Month, i);


            // if Sunday
            if (renderedDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            {
            <td bgcolor="#666666">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox @i" value="check" hidden />
                    <label for="checkbox @i"></label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <h3 align="right" style="color:black">@i</h3>
            </td>
        <tr></tr>
                }
                else if (renderedDay.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                {
                <td bgcolor="#666666">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox @i" value="check" hidden />
                        <label for="checkbox @i"></label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <h3 align="right" style="color:black">@i</h3>
                </td>
                }
                else
                {
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox @i" value="check" hidden />
                        <label for="checkbox @i"></label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <h3 align="right" style="color:black">@i</h3>
                </td>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" align="center">
        <h1 style="color:dodgerblue">Div Direito</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Part of your question involves some HTML-based view-generating technology.  I don't know which but it would help to add a tag for that.

Comment: Sounds like you just want a HTML button which will reload the page, so that the razor code runs again and recreates the calendar? Pretty sure you can google that. Basically a button which runs `window.location.reload()` when the `onclick` event fires. Or maybe just a hyperlink which links to the same page.

Comment: Having said that, why on earth you want to go around changing the clock on your server operating system I don't know, that has the potential to cause all sorts of problems. What problem are you trying to solve here?? What is the requirement for doing such a thing?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to make a button to change the calendar, and I was testing with UtcNow and by changing the date of the OS to see if it worked which it does, that's why I was wondering if there was a button that did the same thing but without changing the actual date

Comment: I have a dropdown with the last 2 months and the current month, and I was wondering how to make when clicking on the buttons to refresh the calendar to that month